# Convert HTML to PDF in asp.net core using DinkToPdf is not working in Ubuntu

Tags: c#, html, pdf, asp.net-core-webapi, dinktopdf

I'm trying to convert an HTML document to PDF, using DinkToPdf in ASP.NET Core Web API version 2.1.

This is my method:

```c#
public async Task<ActionResult> ToPdf()
{
    var loader = new CustomAssemblyLoader();
    var assemblyPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    loader.LoadUnmanagedLibrary($@"{assemblyPath}/libwkhtmltox");
        
    var doc = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
    {
        GlobalSettings = {
            Orientation = Orientation.Landscape,
            PaperSize = PaperKind.A4,
            Out = "wwwroot/test.pdf"
        },
        Objects = {
            new ObjectSettings() {
                PagesCount = true,
                HtmlContent = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In consectetur mauris eget ultrices  iaculis. Utodio viverra, molestie lectus nec, venenatis turpis.",
                WebSettings = { DefaultEncoding = "utf-8" },
                HeaderSettings = { FontSize = 9, Right = "Page [page] of [toPage]", Line = true, Spacing = 2.812 }
            }
        }
    };
    
    _pdfConverter.Convert(doc);
}
```

I copied libwkhtmltox.so and libwkhtmltox.dll to the root of my project, where every .dll is located.

```
sudo apt-get install libgdiplus
```

**Always get this error**

`DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library '/var/www/webapi/webapi/libwkhtmltox' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: /var/www/webapi/webapi/libwkhtmltox: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

By the way, if I run the project on windows works perfect!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you check what is value of `assemblyPath` ? Mb it points to wrong directory

Comment: Yes, checked, it's the root of my project, by the way I also tried without "/"

Comment: Do you have `libgdiplus` installed? `sudo apt install libgdiplus`

Comment: Yes, Installed. sudo apt-get install libgdiplus

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Comment: has anyone found a solution? i am facing the same problem

Comment: I ended creating an app in php just for convert html to pdf, using this library (https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf). This is not a valid solution for the problem, that's why I posted as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command `apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends zlib1g fontconfig libfreetype6 libx11-6 libxext6 libxrender1`. It worked for me!!

Comment: Please edit your answer to be more explanatory. 

Like for example, where is this command to be run on?, 
what are the necessary steps to be taken, 

these would help anyone who wants to utilize your answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my case: net core version 2.1 and main application location on /opt/projects/..

1. I move libwkhtmltox.so to /usr/lib
2. sudo ldconfig
3. sudo ldconfig -v | grep libwk -> (libwkhtmltox.so.0 -> libwkhtmltox.so)

Then download [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)

1. Install all dependency wkhtmltopdf (depend on version)
2. sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox_version.***.deb
3. type wkhtmltopdf --version (just make sure it installed)
4. test wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf

Rerun your application

Comment: On my startup file i didn't use CustomAssemblyLoader. I just add as service -> services.AddSingleton(typeof(IConverter), new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools()));